# Error deploying thin jar via xldeploy and jenkins on linux server

Tags: linux, spring, spring-boot, jar, spring-batch

I have a spring boot/ batch application which is throwing errors when being deployed using jenkins and xldeploy. Its a gradle application.

When I deploy it as a fat jar directly on the server it just works fine, but when I deploy that jar via jenkins and xldeploy it gives me the following error.

> Error creating bean with name 'jobOperator' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [com/one/RetirementConversionImport/standalone/BatchConfiguration.class]:
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not
>   generate CGLIB subclass of class [class
>   com.one.RetirementConversionImport.standalone.BatchConfiguration$1]:
>   Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a
>   non-visible class; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>           at com.paychex.RetirementConversionImport.standalone.RetirementConversionImport.main(RetirementConversionImport.java:85)
>   [RetirementConversionImport.jar:?]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
>   [spring-boot-devtools-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not
>   generate CGLIB subclass of class [class
>   com.paychex.RetirementConversionImport.standalone.BatchConfiguration$1]:
>   Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a
>   non-visible class; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null

Answer (score 1):

The root cause was having spring-boot-devtools in the classpath. Removing devtools solved the problem.So basically in this case problem was with AOP proxy .For some reason we have to turn off the AOP proxy which will ensure that it uses a JDK proxy which could be done by removing the spring-boot-devtools jar, the removal of which will start it to  use the native JDK proxy and fix this error.